# Internet explorer 8 and group policy

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, group-policy, internet-explorer

- Server environment:  Windows Server 2003 R2
- Clients:  Windows XP SP3 with Internet Explorer 6
- Change management:  Conservative

We are planning a phased implementation of IE 8.

The problem is, in our testbed, `Inetres.adm` for IE8 deploys the proxy and bypass settings properly.  Our production environment is using the IE 6 version of the Inetres.adm file.   New IE 8 implementations do not pick up the proxy and bypass settings from our existing GPO.

I dont understand why - The settings are updated in the same registry key as our IE 6 installation. Before we implement the newer `inetres.adm` in our production environment, we'd like to understand why the older one is not doing the job - If there is a problem, we'd like to understand the differences so that we can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a problem like that when we wanted to change our proxy setting in IE8 via GPO after a change in our network architecture.

We tried changing registry, exporting setting of a IE8 correctly configured to a gpo and it still didnt work.

The solution we used was by GPO :

User configuration > Windows Setting > Internet Explorer Maintenance > Connection

We had to change Automatic Browser configuration and Proxy settings.

As i understand it. IE configuration is a User configuration and it must be changed for every user. Maybe if you configure a profile and then copy that profile to default the settings for IE8 will stick for everyone. ( profile copy : easy for xp , harder for w7)